# Mixing SRD Main and d20 Modern SRD

Tags: publishing, ogl

I've read through the legal information and there doesn't seem to be any constraints against mixing [SRD main](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20/article/srd35) and [d20 Modern SRD](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20/article/msrd), but I wanted to double check hoping someone here might know better. I'm currently in the works of making a computer game using the OGL.

Am I allowed to mix the two?

To explain why I would want to do such a thing: I would like to take the Psion class from SRD main and add it as an option into my game along with the point system. I've never played or ran a game with a psion-class in it. Are there problems I should watch out for? Especially if I'm mixing it along with d20 Modern basic classes?

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to split them up into separate questions? I see the OGL question but also the comparison between Psion and modern.

Comment: You might find this other entry useful: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10674/is-it-possible-to-use-rules-from-ogl-or-gsl-in-a-computer-game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sure.** The Open Game License doesn't make distinctions about from which open source you draw content, so long as all of them are legitimately opened under the OGL. Make sure you cite them in your Section 15 and you should be fine.